# subprocess is waiting for password. and stdin is unable to push password

Tags: python, passwords, subprocess

Let me explain you the situation. I am executing tibemsadmin.exe as subprocess.
once the subprocess starts I need to pipe 3 commands.
1. 'connect'
2. username which is ''
3. password which is ''

```
import subprocess as sp
process=sp.Popen('tibemsadmin',cwd='C:/tibco/ems/8.5 - Copy/bin',shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, stdin=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT)
process.stdin.write(b'connect\n')
process.stdin.write(b'\n')
process.stdin.write(b'\n')
stdout=process.communicate()
print(stdout)
cmd.terminate()
```

process is not taking password. It sits for user input. it gets stuck hear

C:\Users\user\Desktop\TIBCO>py cmd_popen.py
Password:

Comment: `stdout=process.communicate()`. this is wrong. use tuple unpacking, `std_out,std_err=process.communicate()`

Comment: Agree with Adam, Also does `process.stdin.close()` before calling `process.communicate()` help? The password could be sitting in the parent's output buffer for the pipe.

Comment: Not really *wrong*, though the name is misleading. You could then use `print(stdout[0])`.

Comment: You can also use `communicate` to pass the input: `stdout, stderr = process.communicate(b'connect\n\n\n')`. *However*, be certain that `tibemsadmin` actually reads credentials from standard input, rather than directly from the terminal.

Comment: This looks like it might help: https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Tibco-KnowledgeArticle-Article-34717

Comment: I tired process.communicate(b'connect\n\n\n'). its also doing teh same thing. Sitting for password. 
And yes. the name is misleading. I updated the main code.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Bemojo yes, I found a workaround. Thanks for asking. I forgot to add the solution. Please upvote if you like the solution.

Answer (score 0):

tibemsadmin process accepts username and password as an argument. so the solution is simple.

```
import subprocess as sp
cmd_tib_connect = "tibemsadmin -server {} -user {} -password {}".format(server_name, user_name, password)
process=sp.Popen(cmd_tib_connect, cwd='C:/tibco/ems/8.5 - Copy/bin',shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, stdin=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.STDOUT)
stdout=process.communicate()
print(stdout)
cmd.terminate()
```

Comment: You still want to prefer a single-line `subprocess.run()` over the multi-line `Popen` + `communicate` + complications and brittleness.